# SonarQube : Enterprise vs Community

Tags: sonarqube

I want to implement sonarqube as a code coverage tool, but I am not sure whether I want to use enterprise or community edition, what is the different between them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That totally depends on what you require:

**Community Edition:**
It comes with the every-day feature that you require like QualityGate
   (custom rule to fail or pass a particular check-in), code smells(best
   practice violation), project rating (manageability check),
   vulnerability scan, Reliability scan etc. essential feature.

[Community Edition: see here](https://www.sonarsource.com/plans-and-pricing/community/)

**Dev, EE and DC Edition:**
They provide you with the git hook to integrate with your project but most of the CI features, branch analysis etc. are restricted to paid versions. Better IDE integration for early detection. And the more you pay for EE and DC edition you get better project management options.

> That totally depends on how you would like to go forward team size,
>   the complexity of the project, release cycles, interoperability etc.

[Other Paid Editions: see here](https://www.sonarsource.com/plans-and-pricing/enterprise/)

Feel free to research further before purchasing.

> **My Suggestion:** First setup the Community edition either on a VM/Machine or Docker, play with it and then decide whether you require
>   extra features.

Comment: You can see here:https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/sonarqube for **Helm** installation, alternatively for **kubernetes** deployment https://github.com/coderise-lab/k8s-sonarqube